# How to get elevation value(Z coordinate) from mesh surface giving X and Y in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, coordinates, terrain

I would like to know if it is possible to get the Z coordinate of point in three js knowing X and Y of this point.
I tested something : I draw a line in this X and Y coordinates and try to get the intersection of this line and the surface(Mesh) generated from tiff file. but many times it tells me that there is no intersection, and if i get one the coordinates of this intersection are (0,0,0). how can I get this Z coordinate ? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzBIR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The example under geometry/terrain/raycast does close to what you are asking.
[(direct clicky)](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast)

Short answer: use a raycaster.

Comment: thank you for your response, effectively I think this is the way to get it. here is the code that I use:    var objects=[]; objects.push(line); objects.push(mesh);var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(objects); but intersects=[] :(

Comment: there are two functions, intersectObject and intersectObjects, be sure to use the right one!  Also you might need to set the recursive flag.